# TeXstudio: keyboard shortcut to jump to last edit

Tags: texstudio

This is something that's a huge time-saver but I cannot seem to find anywhere.

When I'm editing a document in TeXstudio, is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to last edit?

For example, I might be writing something and then need to scroll somewhere else to find the right label, and once I have copied it I want to quickly jump back to where I was.

(I know there are explicit markers with, e.g., `Ctrl+1` but is there an implict one for the place of the last edit in the document?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Edit -> Go to -> Go Back / Go Forward` (Alt+Left/Right).

In the standard configuration this is also available via the yellow arrows in the central vertical toolbar. Also, if your mouse or keyboard have special keys for this operation, they should work.

Answer (score 3):

Not the exact answer, but..
Sometimes I stumble with a similar thing, when I acidentally hit end or home, I learnt to do a Ctrl+z (undo), then a Ctrl+y or Ctrl+Shift+z (redo). this generally will undo your last modification and redo it, leaving you where you was.

Comment: Clever, thanks! I'll wait a while just to see if there's another good shortcut for this, but if not I'll accept this answer. :)